# OpenVPN, two (or more) VPN clients on the same host PC

Tags: vpn, openvpn

I need to have two VPN client on my host.

One client config (#1) is already working, and I need to add the second one (#2) with user passwd authentication without loosing config #1.

How can I achieve this ?

Comment: Just don't use `redirect-gateway` or the equivalent with more than one. If the servers push it, use `pull-filter` to `ignore` it.

Comment: OK, but what about running the 2 clients simultaneously ? I have to execute two OpenVPN process, or can I use one client config file ?

Comment: The former, of course. OpenVPN doesn't work like Wireguard.

Comment: OK. Can you suggest any known tutorial ?

Comment: I have nothing to suggest but the openvpn manual.